# Long HDMI cable doesn't work with my computer, but works with everything else. All ports of video card work

Tags: windows, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a [50' HDMI cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FX867JC) that does not work with my PC.

My graphics card is a Geforce GTX 970, and I'm on Windows 10.

When using the HDMI between and port on my graphics card and any monitor (Tested 3 monitors and 1 TV) I get no signal, or it will "blink" on, then off for about 10 seconds ad infinitum.

The HDMI works though. I've tested with an Xbox One, and another PC, and it works fine.

All the ports on the PC work, I've tested them with the monitors, and a different HDMI cable.

It's only the combination of my PC and this HDMI cable specifically. Any idea what gives?

---

**Edit**: As an additional detail, this was also happening before upgrading to windows 10, it was windows 8.1 prior.

Comment: Is the Amazon link still correct? It now in 2023 says “Twisted Veins HDMI Cable **200 ft**, Long High Speed HDMI Cord with Ethernet, Maximum Length Single Piece Cable – a Replacement Option for an HDMI Extension/Extender” and retails for **$154.99** (!!!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link to the cable you provided:

> This 50' cable supports signals up to 720P/1080i and may support 1080P/4K **depending on your equipment**.

Further:

> Twisted Veins offers a premium version of this cable which supports 1080P/4K signals.  The premium version can be found by at Amazon for "Twisted Veins 50' 4K"

Not all 50' HDMI cables are compliant with the required HDMI specs to support all modes/signal strengths. If they're not fully compliant, then certain devices may not work with them.

So if you're trying to use 1080P, then it's probably not going to work with that cable.  Your XBox and the other PC you tested may not have been in 1080P mode.

For more info, see this related SU question: [How far can an HDMI cable transmit 1080p signal + audio until it becomes lossy?](https://superuser.com/questions/573912/how-far-can-an-hdmi-cable-transmit-1080p-signal-audio-until-it-becomes-lossy?lq=1).

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Do you know if that's going to make it fail regardless? or should downing the resolution at that point affect it? I've tried lower resolutions, so I'm guessing the former.

Comment: You're trying to use a $17 cable to do a length that's basically beyond the spec.  And as such, it's not going to work right with certain devices. Your GTX970 is probably going to be very picky.

Comment: From a link offered in the question I pointed out: "It's true that there are a lot of 50-foot cables on the market, and there are a lot of vendors who play fast and loose with the compliance issue. If you really think your vendor has a compliant 50-foot HDMI cable, ask him for a copy of his compliance testing certificate, which will show the distance for which he's passed testing, and under what spec version. If you find a 50-foot compliant cable (with no booster or EQ unit; more about that below), let us know; we have never found a single one, and we are pretty sure there's no such thing."

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 FWIW, the Amazon link in 2023 seems to be for a 200ft cable that goes for $154.99. Wonder why it changed?

Answer (score 0):

50 feet is just too long; the signal times and losses are too high, depending on what you are trying to connect, it will not work.

I recommend going with a shorter cable if possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz
- Windows 10 Pro
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 Ti

I was having this very same problem.(Not being able to connect with 25' HDMI cable.)

I solved this by making sure I had everything plugged in.

- Turned on laptop (never hot swap cables unless they specifically say they can).
- Then I pulled up the Nvidia control panel from laptop.

When I did this, the connection "magically" activated. That was all it took.

I also found that I could also press my "Video" override button.

Basically an override video switch for my laptop to utilize the onboard Nvidia hardware rather than the standard video adaptor.

While my laptop runs hot (literally the temperature starts rising) when using the video accelerator button, so I normally don't like to use it unless I am running VR or stuff like requires the dedicated video card.

But I can then turn it off of acceleration and it (25' HDMI connection) still works.

Quirky to say the least.